# How to insert all of the selected jcheckbox values into database

Tags: java, database, netbeans, jframe, jcheckbox

I have been trying to insert all of the selected jcheckbox values into a **MySQL** database but could not find any source. I want to do a program where teachers can select all of the courses (`course code`) taken by student and store them into the **database column**. I have tried appending all of the checkbox values into one string variable (code is given below) but don't know how to get all of the courses individually and insert them into database (since courses appear as a string). I have no idea how to do so. However it is also possible to append `jcheckbox` in `jtable` and then select all the rows (which are necessary) to insert into the database.

Please help me with one of the ways stated above. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()) {
    GetAllValues += jCheckBox1.getText() + " ";
}

if (jCheckBox2.isSelected()) {
    GetAllValues += jCheckBox2.getText() + " ";
}

if (jCheckBox3.isSelected()) {
    GetAllValues += jCheckBox3.getText() + " ";
}

if (jCheckBox4.isSelected()) {
    GetAllValues += jCheckBox4.getText() + " ";
}
```

Comment: why dont you pass back list of courses by applying same if check as your code and then insert into db one by one

Comment: Could you please tell me more details